# How to pass lambda to a lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have not managed to find why this code does not
work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  auto xClosure = [](const function<void(int&)>& myFunction) {
    myFunction(10);};

  xClosure([]
       (int& number) -> void
       {cout<<number<<endl;
       });
  return 0;
}
```

It returns:

```
g++ test.cc -o test -std=c++14
```

> ```
>  test.cc:9:5: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const function<void
>   (int &)>'
> ```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has nothing to do with lambdas:

```
void test(const function<void(int&)>& myFunction) {
  myFunction(10);
}
```

this fails to compile for the same reason; you cannot bind the literal `10` to an `int&`.

Maybe you meant

```
const function<void(int)>& myFunction
```

doing so and also modifying the signature of your lambda should make your code compile.